Usage of ellipsis in Python
I have see that when we use ellipsis (three continuous dots ...) in Python, it means different things according to the context. I am aware that ... can be used to omit definition, in typing module (Callable, Tuple etc.), in Pydantic etc.., I looked into the links of SO already which they don't answer my question.
But I am not getting specially what it means when we instantiate a class with ... For example:
class Sample():
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

ref = Sample(...)     <-- I am not sure what this refers.

Can I have some leads please.

You're passing an ellipsis object for the parameter a. That's literally it, nothing more, nothing less.

An Ellipsis object is just a value. It's a value like True or False or None or 42. By itself it doesn't mean and do anything. Your code is free to do something with it.
